# SQLAlchemy func.count with filter

Tags: python, sqlalchemy, flask-sqlalchemy

I'm using a framework that does pagination like this:

```
def get_count_query(self):
    return self.session.query(func.count('*')).select_from(self.model)

def paginate(self):
    ... <irrelevant>...
    count = self.get_count_query.scalar()
    ...
```

I want to override the get_count_query method to use my own query because I'm filtering some results and get_count_query just returns all elements in the table. Queries are created dynamically, for example one query could be:

```
Asset.query.join(StatusLabel).filter(StatusLabel.status == 'Deployable', or_(
                                     Asset.assigned_to.isnot(None)),
                                     Asset.deleted_at.is_(None))
```

I can count the elements in this query easily with `query.count()`:

```
def get_count_query(self):
    q = Asset.query.join(StatusLabel).filter(StatusLabel.status == 'Deployable', or_(
                                             Asset.assigned_to.isnot(None)),
                                             Asset.deleted_at.is_(None))
    return q.count()
```

But this will fail once it reach the .scalar() method (and I cannot remove this method). So the question is: how can I apply `func.count('*')` to an existing query?

Can I retrieve the filters from my query and apply them to the `func.count('*')` query?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use `select_from` with `join` and `filter`

```
def get_count_query(self):
    return self.session.query(func.count('*')).select_from(Asset).join(StatusLabel)\
                                              .filter(StatusLabel.status == 'Deployable', or_(
                                                      Asset.assigned_to.isnot(None),
                                                      Asset.deleted_at.is_(None)))
```

with subquery

```
def get_count_query(self):
    q = Asset.query.join(StatusLabel).filter(StatusLabel.status == 'Deployable', or_(
                                             Asset.assigned_to.isnot(None)),
                                             Asset.deleted_at.is_(None))

    return self.session.query(func.count('*')).select_from(q.subquery())
```

Comment: Thanks for replying but this wont work for me. The query is constructed dynamically, is not all the time the same.

Comment: Thank you very much! I was stucked with this simple problem for hours! :)